# What is learned in convolutional network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

In a convolutional net (CNN), someone answered to me than filters are initialized randomly.

I'm ok for this, but, when there is the gradient descent, who is learning? The features maps, or the filters ?
My intuition is the filters are learning, because they need to recognize complex things.
But I would like to be sure about this.

Comment: you network composed of different kernels. where each of them have the parameters w and b. the GD apply compute the shifting values in these parameters in a way to reduce the error.

Comment: Feature maps are the outputs of your filters/kernels when applying them to inputs (images/feature maps) and hence cannot be learned. Only the parameters (of the filters) to convert inputs to outputs can be learned.

Comment: You might want to read pages 3-10 of [my masters thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09725.pdf#page=17). Especially figure 6.

Comment: Thanks, I will read it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of convolutional neural networks, kernel = filter = feature detector.

Here is a great illustration from [Stanford's deep learning tutorial](http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Feature_extraction_using_convolution) (also nicely explained by [Denny Britz](http://www.wildml.com/2015/11/understanding-convolutional-neural-networks-for-nlp/)).

[image]

The filter is the yellow sliding window, and its value is:

[image]

The feature map is the pink matrix. Its value depends on both the filter and the image: as a result, it doesn't make sense to learn the feature map. Only the filter is learnt when the network is trained. The network may have other weights to be trained as well.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation!
It make sense to me now! :)
Last question, when we have the ouput of a conv layer, let's say 3 features map. And we put an other conv layer next to it with 3 kernels.
The output will be 3 or 9 features map ?
More precisely, the 3 features map of the first layer will be concatenated in a way or other to be processed by the next conv layer or all the features map of the first are send to the next conv like 3 new images ?

Comment: Oh and, why on the first layers, the filters are more likely to extract generale features than the last ones ?

Answer (score 1):

As aleju said, filters weights are learned. Feature maps are outputs of the convolutional layers. Besides convolutional filter weights, there are also weights of fully connected (and other types) layers.